# Como desabilitar as datas antigas na versão Bootstrap Datepiker?

Tags: javascript, html5, datepicker

Não pode escolher a data antiga. Por exemplo: Hoje é dia 18/01/2017, tem que desabilitar 17/01/2017, 16/01/2017 e assim vai ... Não pode desabilitar data de hoje e futuro.

Aqui está o código completo na versão jquery :http://jsfiddle.net/yTMwu/216/

Como fazer isso na versão [bootstrap datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ?

Comment: Está utilizando [esta lib](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: @Randrade, isso mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, basta utilizar o `startDate`, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
$('input').datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: 'd'
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Caso queira dias no passado ou futuro, pode alterar para `startDate: '-5d'` ou `startDate: '+5d'`, que irá colocar a data inicial para 5 dias antes (-5d) ou 5 dias após (+5d).

Comment: Nossa, é tão simples assim ?

Comment: Por mais incrível que pareça, sim.

Answer (score 2):

use a opção `startDate`

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate

ex:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: 'data_desejada'
});
```

Comment: Gabriel Weber, obrigado pela a sua resposta, eu agradeço